# MYSQL - Multiple counts in a single query

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to do multiple counts in a single query but still not getting the results I want.
There are 6 servers on 5F / 6F and I want to count how many servers on 5F / 6F are using CPU more than 50%
or how many servers on 5F / 6F are using CPU less than 50%.

I tried to send the below query but the result is not separated by group.

```
SELECT room, (SELECT count( > 50) FROM table WHERE empty > 50),
(SELECT count( < 50) FROM table WHERE empty < 50) FROM table GROUP BY location;
```

Table:

```
| name  | location | CPU usage |
| host1 | 5F       | 60        |
| host2 | 5F       | 20        |
| host2 | 5F       | 80        | 
| host3 | 6F       | 30        |
| host4 | 6F       | 40        |
| host5 | 6F       | 90        |
```

Desired output:

```
| location | > 50 | < 50 |
| 5F       | 2    | 1    |
| 6F       | 1    | 2    |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT location, SUM(IF(cpu_usage > 50, 1, 0)), SUM(IF(cpu_usage <=50, 0, 1))
FROM table
GROUP BY location
```

### Updated

As  ScayTrase mentioned, `cpu_usage > 50` itselfs return 0 or 1 for true or false respectively. So, preceding query could be simplified as follows.

```
SELECT location, SUM(cpu_usage > 50), SUM(cpu_usage <=50)
FROM table
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: And, just define column aliases as `as '> 50'` and `as '< 50'`

Comment: Just `SUM(cpu_usage > 50)`, no `IF`, because cpu_usage > 50 casts to 1 or 0 by itself.